# Will Using a 32-bit Library Make My Entire App Run in 32-bit Mode?

Tags: ios

this is just a general question about application behavior. I apologize if it's a bit broad, but I haven't been able to find a real answer online.

I'm using Swift to create an iOS app. I need to use an older library/plugin that only runs in 32-bit mode.

The library is basically where a lot of the main functionality of the application will come from.

**I know 32-bit apps work on 64-bit OS's, but does that mean that the entire application will run in 32-bit mode, or is it only the sections that use the library/plugin?**

Thank you all.